# Search between multiple collections in elasticsearch having common fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I have two different collections as shown in table:

- T-shirt having fields [Size, ID]
- Brand having fields [Name, ID]

I need to search for only small sized T-shirt of Nike brand. The query should be like  `Size equals Small AND Name equals Nike` but the `AND` operation does not give any result and the OR operation gives all four results of small sized t-shirt and nike brand. Both the collections are bound by common `ID` field. Is there any way to solve this?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best possible solution is to denormalize the tables.